# vba arrays manipulation hard coding syntax

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, syntax

hard coding array manipulation in c based languages is common, like below:

```
int i[] = new i[2][2];
i = {{1,1},{2,2}};
```

how it could be done in vba scripts?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the [`Array()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to build an array of values.

I haven't tried it, but I suspect you could do what you want with this:

```
Dim i as Variant
i = Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 2))
```

It's been a while, so my VBA is a bit rusty.